# Not able to run airflow in Cloud run getting error disk I/o error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run airflow in google cloud run.
Getting error Disk I/O error, I guess the disk write permission is missing.

can someone please help me with this how to give write permission inside cloud run.
I also have to write file and later delete it.
[image: Error in cloud run logs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the directory `/tmp` is writable in Cloud Run. So, change the default write location to write into this directory.

However, you have to be aware of 2 things:

- Cloud Run is stateless, that means when a new instance is created, the container start from scratch, with an empty `/tmp` directory
- `/tmp` directory is an in-memory file system. The maximum allowed memory on Cloud Run is 2Gb, your app memory footprint included. In addition of your file and Airflow, not sure that you will have a lot of space.

A final remark. Cloud Run is active only when it process request, and a request has a maximum timeout of 15 minutes. When no request, the allowed cpu is close to 0%. I'm not sure of what you want to achieve with Airflow on Cloud Run, but my feeling tells me that your design is strange. And I prefer to warn you before you spend too much effort on this.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Cloud Run service has evolved in the right way. In 2022,

- `/tmp` is no longer the only writable directory (you can write everywhere, but it's still in memory)
- the timeout is no longer limited to 15 minutes, but to 60 minutes
- The [2nd gen runtime execution](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/execution-environments) (still in preview) allows you to mount NFS (Filestore) or Cloud Storage (GCSFuse) volume to have services "more stateful".

You can also execute jobs now. So, a lot of very great evolution!

Comment: Thanks @guillaume
I was just playing with cloud run trying to set up Airflow with cloud run. let me know if I can attach an external harddisk with Run.
Is there any alternative in GCP like ECS in AWS where I can host airflow with cost effective manner.

Comment: @DeepakPoojari - Google has an Airflow service: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview

Comment: @DeepakPoojari all depends what you expect by "cost effective". Cloud Composer (as mentioned by John ) is a managed airflow. $400 per month, not really cheap but you have nothing to manage: you have a website, a SQL database, a cluster of VM for the worker and a Redis (memory store) for state share (Xcom) between worker. Do it yourself, manage it and maintain it, not sure that you will find cheaper!!

Comment: @DeepakPoojari, about the disk, you can't, Cloud Run (and Knative serving) contract is : stateless container (no persistent disk) and answer to HTTP request (no batch, no cron, no background process,...)

Comment: Thanks  @guillaume blaquiere
I tried to run it on google app engine.
It runs but again stops execution with in a few. Do app engine allow background jobs?

Comment: Yes and No. App Engine automatic scaling doesn't allow background jobs. Basic and manual scaling allows them, in addition of App Engine flexible version. But you loose in elasticity and, thus, in cost saving/optimisation.

Comment: @maxwell what is missing in the doc?

Comment: that you can only write to `/tmp/`. cc @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @maxwell: because it's no longer the case! I updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

My impression is that you have a write i/o error because you are using SQLite. Is that possible.

If you want to run Airflow using cointainers, I would recommend to use Postgres or MySQL as backend databases.

You can also mount the plugins and dag folder in some external volume.